# C# Intellisense auto-completion just stopped working

Tags: c#, autocomplete, intellisense

I can still see the recommended completions but I used to just be able to hit enter and it would fill it in, now I have to manually click down on my arrow keys and then hit enter. It's slightly annoying after hours of it.

I already tried turning the intellisense on and  off in the options tab.

Comment: maybe pressing Tab will work

Comment: Which editor are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This does Happen a lot to me to. I recommend that you turn it off, And restart your computer. Once your computer is on, Just turn it back on. This fixed it for me, and I hope that it fixes for you.